# Fixing GNU Octave without science repo in openSUSE

Tags: octave, opensuse

I am a user of openSUSE 13.2.   While updating the openSUSE, the system stopped working properly (for example, unable to open firefox, or software management in yast2.  Snapper does not work to fix that). So I used DVD openSUSE 13.2 to upgrade (update) and it managed to fix it.  However, some applications such as GNU Octave is not working.  I am able to open it and run it but it gives me errors with compiling example code.  Errors such as missing libraries etc.  I do not want to jump to openSUSE 15 with so much hassle with it.  I just want to fix Octave for now.  However, science repository for openSUSE 13.2 is no longer active.  I have GNU Octave v. 3.8 and if possible I would like to update octave to latest version with all the octave packages available.  How I do it without science repository available for openSUSE 13.2.  Is it okay to use repo of other openSUSE version say SLE?

Below is a sample code:

```
x = -10:0.1:10;
c=pi
d=exp(0)
f1 = sin(x);
f2 = c.^(1/4)* x.*exp((-1/2)*x.^2);
plot(x,f1,'-r',x,f2,'-b')
title ("psi(x) at n=0 and n=1 for x = -10:0.1:10");
xlabel ("x");
ylabel ("psi(x)");
text (0.6, 1.2, "psi at n=0");
text (-0.6, -0.8, "psi at n=1");
legend ('psi-0(x)','psi-1(x)');
```

and the GNU Octave output is

```
error: /usr/lib64/octave/3.8.2/oct/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu/PKG_ADD:    /usr/lib64/octave/3.8.2/oct/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu/__init_fltk__.oct: failed     to load: /usr/lib64/octave/3.8.2/oct/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu/__init_fltk__.oct: undefined symbol: _ZN9Fl_Window6cursorE9Fl_Cursor
error: called from:
 error:   /usr/lib64/octave/3.8.2/oct/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu/PKG_ADD at     line 6, column 1
 GNU Octave, version 3.8.2
  Copyright (C) 2014 John W. Eaton and others.

There is ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  For details, type 'warranty'.

Octave was configured for "x86_64-suse-linux-gnu".

For information about changes from previous versions, type 'news'.

 warning: function /home/adam/OctaveExamples/waitbar.m shadows a       core library function
   warning: function /home/adam/OctaveExamples/plot3.m shadows a core    library function
  plot1
  c =  3.1416
  d =  1
  error: default graphics toolkit 'fltk' is not available!
  error: base_graphics_toolkit::initialize: invalid graphics toolkit
  error: called from:
  error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.2/m/plot/util/figure.m at line 94,      column 9
  error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.2/m/plot/util/gcf.m at line 63, column 9
  error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.2/m/plot/util/newplot.m at line 113, column 8
  error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.2/m/plot/draw/plot.m at line 219, column 9
  error:   /home/adam/OctaveExamples/plot1.m at line 6, column 1
```

the code was working before the openSUSE mulfunctioned.  After the fix, octave seems to be broken.

Comment: does opensuse have something equivalent to apt-get build-dep octave in debian systems that would install all the dependencies for you? if so, I would recommend you do that, and then install octave from source. Alternatively, octave also seems to support the flatpak format these days.

Comment: flatpak is supported by latest version of opensuse.  13.2 is not listed in flatpak support.

Comment: have you tried `sudo zypper rm octave && sudo zypper in octave` ?

Comment: @Andy yes, I have tried and it does not work.  The error starts with init fltk.